# How to scroll to the bottom or top of a div with overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, overflow

I have some div with a lot of content, i want to scroll some divs inside the main div into view. so this is mainly the y-overflow scroll with x-overflow hidden.

**I don't want to scroll the window or body but only the div's contents.**

```
$(document).on("click", ".CommentBut", function() {
 //////when the Comment button is clicked.////
 $('#QuickRead').scrollTop()
////Scroll Quick Read Div to the top./////
});
```

But the above is not working and i think probably there's something wrong with my method or syntax.

Comment: use $(window).scrollTop() instead of $('#QuickRead').scrollTop();

Comment: I don't want to scroll the window but the inside of the div $('#QuickRead')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following to goto top  , here take dom element by ID, then do scrolling ,1st parameter is where to scroll (in pixels) ,2nd is time to scrolling.

```
jQuery("#QuickRead").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1);
```

To goto bottom :

```
  var $target = jQuery("#QuickRead"); 
  $target.animate({scrollTop: $target.height()}, 1000);
```

Comment: You are scrolling the page, i want to scroll the contents of the div not the page.

Comment: then use  jQuery("#QuickRead") instead of  jQuery("html,body")

Comment: If you get the ans , use upvoting,chossing correct ans. thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you use Jquery instead of the dollar sign?

Comment: Its shorthand.Do you like to use jQuery or $ ,which is small?

Comment: Do you like to be called by name=>   "user3109875" or  "your actual name(like sam)" ?

Answer (score 1):

well you can say its a kind of bug.
Some browsers apply the "overall" scroll to document.documentElement (the  element) and others to document.body (the  element). For compatibility with both, you have to apply the scrolling to both..

try below thing

```
if($.browser.safari) bodyElement = $("body")
else bodyElement = $("html,body")

bodyElement.scrollTop(100)
```

update :

```
$("#QuickRead").animate({scrollTop:$('#div_id').position().top}, 'slow');
```

Comment: I don't want to scroll the body.